# MVC C# website + WordPress at the same Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, web-config

I have MVC C# App running, I have created subfolder for the WordPress and I am trying to serve the WordPress articles at the same domain so let's say the article is at

***https://example.com/wordpress/article_title***

and I want it to be

***https://example.com/article_title***

at the main url without the WordPress in the URL

I have done the changes on the WordPress site, but the main issue now is the web config file

how can I write a rewrite rule for the WordPress to be working at the main directory because at the moment the config file doesn't have a clue about the WordPress URLs and it's returning 404

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method worked for me

1. first I moved the index.php from the WordPress folder to the man directory and changed the required dir to the correct folder require **DIR** . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php';
2. added the following code to the web.config file to redirect all URLs which end with forward slash to be served as WordPress page

```
<rule name="WordPress: https://example.com/wordpress/" patternSyntax="WordPress">
            <match url="*/"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
```

tope this will help someone but the most important to make sure that the MVC website not serving any page ending with forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following rewrite rule

```
<rules>
                <rule name="TestPattern" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^[^/]+$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="wordpress/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" />
                </rule>
</rules>
```

**Case 1**

This rule will ingore all the follwoing patterns having slash let's say if your asp.net mvc application routing matches the following url, then this rule will allow this url to pass to your mvc routing table and your MVC pages can be served

- https://example.com/controllername/actionname
- https://example.com/abc/controllername/actionname

**Case 2**

If you try following pattern as you described, this rule will redirect you to your respective wordpress folder and you will be good to go

- https://example.com/article_title

**Case 3**

There is still one way that would cause an issue if your mvc app routing table contains the following structure then you need to either change that routing in your mvc app like **actionname/controllername** or change your wordpress redirect pattern

- https://example.com/actionanme
- https://example.com/controllername

Comment: Thanks for you comment
this is not going to work as the WordPress main Index file is moved at the main directory, and the articles permalink doesn't have WordPress in it it's straight forward example.com/article